# Error - function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2), is displayed when trying to fetch time in fixed format

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, time, datetime-format

I am trying to fetch the **time** in the following format, but I'm getting error that function is missing required argument for '**month**'. It would be a great help if someone could resolve this small confusion.

```
import datetime
startTimeList = ['drwxr-xr-x  3 plan 4096 Mar 21 02:00 file_listener', 'ksh', '010001', '0\n']
startTimeStr = int(startTimeList[2])
print(startTimeStr)
startTimeStr = datetime.datetime(startTimeStr)
startTime = startTimeStr.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
print(startTime)
```

Expected Output:

```
010001
01:00:01 AM
```

Error Displayed:

```
function missing required argument 'month' (pos 2)
```

Comment: Why `PM` and not `AM`?

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake. Corrected now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting `startTimeList[2]` to an integer was not helping you, as you needed to convert it back to a string again.

[`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) expects integer arguments *year*, *month*, *day*, which is not what you wanted to do.

You meant to use [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to parse the string `'010001'` into a `datetime.datetime` object, which you can then convert to a differently formatted string with `strftime` again:

```
import datetime

startTimeList = ['drwxr-xr-x  3 plan 4096 Mar 21 02:00 file_listener', 'ksh', '010001', '0\n']
startTimeStr = startTimeList[2]
print(startTimeStr)

startTime = datetime.datetime.strptime(startTimeStr, "%H%M%S")
startTimeResult = startTime.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p")
print(startTimeResult)
```

It gives you `01:00:01 AM` however, since it has no way of knowing that `010001` means a *pm* time.